Error with Joomla CIVICRM 5.73.0 frontend membership form page not advancing to review your contribution
After my upgrade from 5.70.0 to 5.73.0 on Joomla 5.10 I noticed that the membership page on the frontend website when a member that is logged in tries to pay their membership (the membership form) by clicking "review your contribution" button it just refreshes the screen back to the membership online form. It doesnt go to the next step of verifying your information. There are no errors showing for this issue in the civicrm logs or php errors log. It happens on both credit card and pay later. I also tried different browsers with same results.
When I restore back to 5.70.0 the form works just fine.
Thanks in advance for your help.

What happends if you disable the confirmation page in the Contribution Page settings?

FWIW ... I had updated to 5.73 a month ago, and hadn't tried the event registration.  Someone contacted me today with this issue, and I then remembered that I had to fix it for the 5.72 update.
Changed out the civicrm.php file under the site components, and it works fine now.  Am now keeping a copy of that file where I can get to it again easily in future until the code is updated.

I had similar issues and have found that it's "something" in the 5.72.0 upgrade that has caused the issue as well as others.
I'm trying now to work through what's in 5.72.0 and see if I can isolate the cause.
I'm running Joomla 4.4.4 as well

See my answer, please.

This is probably the same issue as Event registrations failing on 5.72.1 in Joomla with 'Could not find valid value for id' caused by a bad attempt (by me) at modernizing the CiviCRM Joomla plugin which will stop working with Joomla 5.
NOTE: The new, updated code in 5.72.0 requires recreating any CiviCRM-related menu entries in Joomla. This should have been in the release notes but did not make it there. Please try that.
If that does not help, the fix in that other question will probably help for now.
I'm working on debugging this to see if there are other situations this does not work.
UPDATE: I have created a CiviCRM issue for this, please add information about your setup there so I can re-create and test it.

Thank you for your work on this. My setup is PHP Built On Linux s442.sureserver.com 5.15.146-sure #1 SMP Mon Jan 15 05:59:48 EST 2024 x86_64
Database Type mysql
Database Version 8.0.35-percona-sure1
Database Collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
Database Connection Collation utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
Database Connection Encryption None
Database Server Supports Connection Encryption Yes
PHP Version 8.1.28
Web Server Apache
WebServer to PHP Interface fpm-fcgi
Joomla! Version Joomla! 5.1.0 Stable [ Kudumisha ] 16-April-2024 16:00 GMT I will post my setup there as well.

Thanks @BJM. I think the technical details are less important. What I need is your setup in terms of menus, functions etc. that are giving this problem. E.g. given a menu which leads to a membership page... Can you give me instructions on how to set up that? I have no experience with memberships.

Can you please try the updated code pointed to in the issue I mentioned in this answer?
